# Code under conditional statement is not executing despite condition being met

Tags: python, list, if-statement

maybe it's because I haven't coded for a few days, but I can't understand why this isn't working. The condition of   if i == enemy_spaceship_index    is being met once in the for loop, and yet the code beneath that conditional if statement is not executing. When I print out the list, it's just giving me seven 2s. What is should be doing is printing six 2s and a 3. The position of the 3 in the list is determine by enemy_spaceship_index. Any help would be appreciated.

```
enemy_spaceship_index = randint(0, 6)
appearancesLeft = []

for i in range(7):
        if i == enemy_spaceship_index:
            appearancesLeft.append(3)
        elif i != enemy_spaceship_index:
            appearancesLeft.append(2)

    print appearancesLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your indentation is messed up. Otherwise, it looks to me like your code works just fine...

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> for x in range(7): # test all possible values
...     enemy_spaceship_index = x
...     appearancesLeft = []
...     for i in range(7):
...         if i == enemy_spaceship_index:
...             appearancesLeft.append(3)
...         elif i != enemy_spaceship_index:
...             appearancesLeft.append(2)
...         print appearancesLeft
...
[3]
[3, 2]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 3, 2]
[2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2]
[2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
[2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
[2]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I fixed the code for you, this is working now:

```
    import random

    enemy_spaceship_index = random.randint(0, 6) 
    appearancesLeft = []

    for i in range(7):
            if i == enemy_spaceship_index:
                appearancesLeft.append(3)
            elif i != enemy_spaceship_index:
                appearancesLeft.append(2)

    print appearancesLeft
```

Always make sure you keep intend levels right and all libraries imported

Comment: you've got a missing newline before "appearancesLeft = []"